# Превышение длины Get-запроса при формировании returnURL .Net 6

Tags: asp.net-core, url, get

На каждой странице у меня есть получение текущего адреса

```
//Текущий URL
string currentURL = Context.Request.GetDisplayUrl();
```

и передача его при переходе по сайту в параметре контроллера returnURL. Пример:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync ([CanBeNull] string returnURL, int page = 1)
   {
      //Проверка returnURL
      returnURL ??= GetSiteMainPageUrl();
      ...
   }
```

и ссылка на него

```html
<a asp-action="Index" asp-area="account" asp-controller="Users" asp-route-returnURL="@currentURL" class="nav-link">
   <span class="fas fa-users"></span>
   &nbsp;
   Пользователи сайта
</a>
```

То есть получается вот такая ссылка:

```
https://localhost:44304/account/Users?returnURL=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44304%2
```

При переходе на следующую страницу такая:

```
https://localhost:44304/account/Users/Filter?returnURL=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44304%2Faccount%2FUsers%3FreturnURL%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A44304%252
```

Вы, наверное, уже догадались, что в итоге ловлю

> HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found
>
> Модуль фильтрации запросов настроен таким образом, чтобы не пропускать слишком длинные строки запросов.

и понятно из-за чего. Как можно передавать в returnURL все параметры запроса для страницы, исключая её returnURL или как организовать такие переходы по-другому. POST тоже не выход, так как он в итоге будет так загружать страницу, что проще от этой идеи отказаться...

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ:** Получается 2 выхода, как мне видится:

1. Создать парсер текста, который будет находить второй returnURL и удалять его;
2. Использовать middleware и session. С помощью 1-го дополнить контекст словарём, загружаемым из сессии (с чего начать?)

Answer (score 0):

Пока получилось решить вопрос (благодаря [этому вопросу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992848/parse-and-modify-a-query-string-in-net-core)) так:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Очищает URL, удаляя ненужные QueryString
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="helper"><see cref="IUrlHelper"/></param>
    /// <param name="context"><see cref="HttpContext"/></param>
    /// <param name="url">Ссылка, которую нужно почистить</param>
    /// <param name="clearQueryString">Массив ключей, которые нужно удалить</param>
    /// <param name="getLocalURL">Возвращать только локальную ссылку</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [NotNull]
    public static string ParseURLQuery([NotNull] IUrlHelper helper, HttpContext context, [CanBeNull] string url,
        [NotNull] List<string> clearQueryString, bool getLocalURL = true)
    {
        //Получаю returnURL
        url ??= "/";

        //Если адрес локальный, то преобразую в полный
        if (helper.IsLocalUrl(url))
            url = $"{context.Request.Scheme}://{context.Request.Host}{url}";

        //Создаю uri по адресу
        Uri uri = new(url);

        UriFormat format = UriFormat.UriEscaped;

        //Формирую Uri-адрес сайта
        string baseUri =
            uri.GetComponents(UriComponents.Scheme | UriComponents.Host | UriComponents.Port,
                format);

        //Формирую локальную ссылку
        string localUri = uri.GetComponents(UriComponents.Path, format);

        //Создаю словарь запроса
        Dictionary<string, StringValues> query = QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(uri.Query);

        //Если он содержит параметр для очистки, то удаляю его
        foreach (string s in clearQueryString.Where(s => query.ContainsKey(s)))
            query.Remove(s);

        //Запускаю построение новых параметров
        QueryBuilder qBuilder = new(query);

        //Создаю переменную-результат
        string result = "";

        //Если нужно получить полную ссылку
        if (!getLocalURL)
            result = baseUri;

        //формирую переменную-результат
        result = $"{result}/{localUri}{qBuilder.ToQueryString()}";

        //Вывожу результат
        return result;
    }
```

Как его можно улучшить?